# 406 (Not Acceptable) Error when i try to open a ngBootbox with html template

Tags: angularjs, iis, xmlhttprequest

I have an angular app with Web Api in ASP.NET. When I'm working locally the app show the ngBootbox correctly, but when I run the app fom the server (IIS 7.5), chrome returns a 406 (Not acceptable) error. In network tab in developer tools I have the next result when I try to call the ngBootbox:

[This is the result I get when i call the ngBootbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Tfq.png)

I've tried all the possible solutions that I found on the internet like add a MIME type in IIS Manager and I tried to use different ways to call a modal window but nothing worked.

I have another ngBootbox that works fine but that one doesn't use a html template

I've also tried to use ngDialog and $uibModal to show a modal window but is the same thing.

I'm so desperate to find a solution, I will be so thankful with you.

Note: This is my first post here, and I don't know if I did my question correctly.

Ok, here is the button I'm using to call the ngBootbox window:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"
            ng-bootbox-title="Registrar Llamada"
            ng-bootbox-custom-dialog
            ng-bootbox-custom-dialog-template="templates/calls.html"
            ng-bootbox-buttons="buttons" 
            ng-click="setClientInfo(client.Id, client.Nombre)">
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
            </button>
```

Here is the template I'm using in "ng-bootbox-custom-dialog-template":

```
<div class="card" ng-controller="callController">
<div class="card-body card-padding">
    <div>
        <toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 3000, 'close-button':true, 'position-class': 'toast-bottom-right'}"></toaster-container>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="position:relative; top:30px; left:20px;">
        <div class="fg-line">
            <md-input-container class="md-block; col-sm-5;" flex-gt-sm>
                <label>Cliente</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="client.ClientName" ng-disabled="true">
            </md-input-container>
        </div>

        <div class="fg-line">
            <md-input-container class="md-block; col-sm-5;" flex-gt-sm>
                <label>Fecha de Llamada</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="date" ng-disabled="true">
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div class="fg-line">
            <md-input-container class="md-block; col-sm-5;">
                <label>Observaciones</label>
                <textarea required="true" ng-model="call.Observations" md-maxlength="200" rows="4" md-select-on-focus style="width: 380px;"></textarea>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveCall(call)" style="position:relative; top:-15px; left:05px;"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbspRegistrar Llamada</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my app.js:

```
var app = angular
.module('RDash', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.router',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngAnimate',
    'toaster',
    'ngDialog',
    'datatables',
    'datatables.buttons',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngBootbox',
    'nvd3'
]).config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
$httpProvider.useApplyAsync(true);
```

}]);

I think i'm missing something in .config but im not sure...

Comment: Share the code that calls the link/url/page being loaded. It is possible that the issue might be the way call is made.

Comment: Please post the relevant code you're using, as well as error message as shown in the logs.

Comment: Code posted @THeron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means in your request you are sending accept header with some value but server (API) is generating response in format not acceptable by client. e.g. If your request contains accept header as application/xml and server (API) is generating response of type application/json that means response generated by server is not acceptable by client as its accepting response only in application/xml format. Check what value of "Accept" header you are sending and in what format api is generating response.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking for accept headers... you know which accept header is for xhr?

Comment: Your accept headers will depend on what type of response API is generating. If you omit accept header in request browser will auto detect it and you don't need to worry about it. But if you are explicitly passing accept header in request then it has to match with server response type. You can check what you are sending currently in developer tools by selecting request in network tab and examining headers tab.

Comment: Its working now! Just deleting the next line: $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";    Thanks a lot!!!!